# Failed to open stream but other in the other functions is it working

Tags: php

My php script gives a Failed to open stream err. But it's only in that function. I just copied the `require "../config/defaultVars.inc.php"; require "../config/db.inc.php";`

I don't understand why?? I just copied it and the other functions are working perfectly[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpl7U.png).

I tried all other import functions like include, require_once

Comment: Check the file paths see `__FILE__`. see `var_dump(realpath("../config/defaultVars.inc.php"))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The I solved the problem, I made the way to the file different (changed the path). So my php code could find the file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).